# Postman API call is not Working when exported and run in PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, postman

I am trying to create an API call to obtain an access token. My call is working as it should in postman. Following is the collection extracted.

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "1861078c-8a9a-49a2-8a4b-88591ca750a8",
        "name": "asdf",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "asdf Access Token Generation",
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "basic": [
                        {
                            "key": "password",
                            "value": "asd",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "asd",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "warning": "This is a duplicate header and will be overridden by the Authorization header generated by Postman.",
                        "key": "Authorization",
                        "value": "Basic",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "grant_type",
                        "value": "client_credentials",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "client_credentials",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://uatopenapi.abc.com:8243/token",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "uatopenapi",
                        "abc",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "port": "8243",
                    "path": [
                        "token"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I generated the following code using Postman. (I actually made many tweaks but none of them would be useful since the basic code is not working in the first place. I am showing the code generated from postman for convenient understanding of my issue.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "8243",
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://uatopenapi.abc.com:8243/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Authorization: Basic YXNkOmFzZA==",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host: uatopenapi.abc.com:8243",
    "Postman-Token: 1e4bc145-76c9-40d4-bd80-c23af17fa8a4,b1c0e5ce-2142-40f3-a378-d536acd24d2e",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-length: 29"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

The error I'm getting from the `php` script is **cURL Error #:Failed to connect to uatopenapi.abc.com port 8243: Connection refused**

API requires me that the credentials are `base64` encoded. In the live script I remove all postman tokens and other metadata. I cannot figure out why the same postman collection does not give an error when I export and run it as a `php` script.

I tried removing postman metadata values, removing port number, replacing request type with `CURLOPT_POST => true` and adding `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false`

Comment: Could this be a proxy issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you try to remove any content-length param, postman-token, cookie param generated from the code generator on Postman, and it should work as its own specific request. Thats a start. Also Check whether you require some .PEM certificate for SSL authentication.

Remove

```
"Postman-Token: 1e4bc145-76c9-40d4-bd80-c23af17fa8a4,b1c0e5ce-2142-40f3-a378-d536acd24d2e"
"content-length: 29"
"User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
```

Comment: Yes, all such parameters are removed. I mentioned all those data to show that even the same req generated from postman is not working let alone a modified req. of my needs